# How should I implement dependency injection in WinUI3 Application?

Tags: dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

There are multiple ways of implementing dependency injection in a WinUI3 application, and I don't see the differences.

For example, what are the differences between these?

First implementation:

```cs
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
    .Build();

var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddSingleton<IExempleService, ExempleService>();
services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();

services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(
    options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    },
    ServiceLifetime.Scoped
);

services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Second implementation:

```cs
Host = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.
CreateDefaultBuilder().
UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory).
ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
{
    services.AddSingleton<IExempleService, ExempleService>();

    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
    );
}).
Build();
```

Comment: This is a general Microsoft DI question. What's specific about WinUI3?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, when it comes to DI.  The second implementation again gets to `ServiceCollection`, but HostBuilder provides additional services.

Answer (score 0):

The second code listing is using a [generic host](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host). In addition to configuration and dependency injection, it includes hooks for logging and application lifetime. It also provides a good framework for adding [background services](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/extensions/workers).